# Mixing Numbered and Un-Numbered Sections in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

In my table of contents, I need to have some entries numbered, and some un-numbered, but still have the number increment on un-numbered parts.

In other words, I need:

```
1 - First Section Title

2 - Second Section Title

Third Section Title (un-numbered)

4 - Fourth Section Title
```

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}  
\section*{Third Section Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Third Section Title} 
\section{Fourth Section Title}

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

But this results in "Fourth Section Title" getting a number of 3 in the Table of Contents. How do I get it to have a 4?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Should this occur for any unnumbered section or just for the shown one?

Comment: Any un-numbered section, there will be lots in the real document.

Comment: See my answer please, but it's a little bit inconsistent to continue the numbering

Comment: I can think to no reason for this. If the numbering increases, why should the number be omitted for some of the sections?

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way is to patch the `\@startsection` command, which is responsible for the starting of a section and look for the `\@ifstar` macro inside.
Add a `\stepcounter{section}` there only if the section level is `section` (`\refstepcounter is of no use, in my point of view).

This must be done after `\tableofcontents` since all ToC-like commands use `\section*{}` for the ToC heading.

Be careful with `\printindex` and `\bibliography` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@startsection}{%
  \@ifstar
  {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
}{%
  \@ifstar
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{section}{\stepcounter{section}}{}%
    \@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
}{\typeout{Yes}}{\typeout{No!}}
\makeatother
\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}  
\section*{Third Section Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Third Section Title} 
\section{Fourth Section Title}
\subsection*{Test subsection}
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked fine. Although, what do you mean by "be careful with \printindex and \bibliography"? What bad things will happen?

Comment: `\printindex` etc. usually use `\section*{...}` too, so this will lead to additional `\stepcounter` commands then. If there are no numbered sections after index etc. this is no problem, unless your code relies on a certain total number of sections (which is not the case, most likely)

Comment: Now also a `\subsection*` command would step `section`

Comment: @egreg: True, I forgot that `\@ssect` is used in any of those structuring commands. I'll change

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to the KOMA-classes and patch `\addsec`. This would also remove the need for the `\addcontentsline`. But imho the numbering is curious. It looks as if the typesetter made an error and forget a number.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\addsec{\refstepcounter{section}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}

\addsec{Third Section Title}

\section{Fourth Section Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just define a special command, instead of abusing `\section*`. When you'll change your mind and decide not to do such a funny thing, you'll just have to replace `\specialsection` with `\section`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}  
\section*{Third Section Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Third Section Title} 
\section{Fourth Section Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An advanced version where `\specialsection` admits the same syntax as `\section` (with an optional argument for the `toc` entry):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialsection}{\@dblarg\special@section}
\def\special@section[#1]#2{%
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \section*{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}
\specialsection{Third Section Title}
\section{Fourth Section Title}

\end{document}
```